# How can i check the data which is sent out internet?

Tags: java, jnetpcap

I want to check data is sent out to the internet.
I tried with jnetcap example [here](http://jnetpcap.com/examples)

I can use the below code to check receive packages:

```
PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {  

            public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {  

                System.out.printf("Received packet at %s caplen=%-4d len=%-4d %s\n",  
                    new Date(packet.getCaptureHeader().timestampInMillis()),   
                    packet.getCaptureHeader().caplen(),  // Length actually captured  
                    packet.getCaptureHeader().wirelen(), // Original length   
                    user                                 // User supplied object  
                    );  
            }  
        };
```

but i did not see any example about sent package?
How can i track the sent-package by this api or any similar api (java)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood.

"Received" in that context means packets "received" from pcap by the application. It doesn't mean packets received by the machine from the network.

That example captures both incoming *and* outgoing packets. It's up to you to determine the difference by examining the various protocol headers. See [`PcapPacket`](http://jnetpcap.com/docs/javadocs/jnetpcap-1.4/index.html) for more info about getting the actual captured data.

Comment: Thank you, i will check again

Comment: hi @Jason C, i had file A and i want to check content of file A is existed on PcapPacket  ? can you give me suggestion or article?